# vim:confirm before closing multiple tabs

Tags: vim

I often unintentionaly quit vim using :qa while open many files in different tabs. I wonder if there is any way to have something like a confirmation line showing before closing multiple tabs and quit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ised to use this plugin: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1072 but as far as I remember it only works with the GUI version.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this. But what I want is a much simpler version just like when the file you opened changed outside, it'll prompt you to reload. Thanks anyway!